# Print to screen and Log at the same time

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I'm using .Net CORE and i'm writing a program that print logs to screen and also save the logs into  a file .
So my entire code full with lines like this:

```
        Console.WriteLine("starting app");
        Log.Debug("stating app");
        if (args.Length < 2)
        {
            Log.Debug("got less than 2 arguments");
            Console.WriteLine("Should be run with arguments:");
            Console.WriteLine("<DirecotryPath> <OutputPath>");
            return;
```

Is there is away to prevent this duplication in my code? 
Thank you

Comment: Other than you have not demonstrated duplication.. make a method "Log_n_Display" and have it do both?

Comment: Any descent logging framework can write message into multiple destination at the same time: file, screen, remote log-service, etc. Just look into [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/) or [log4net](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/)

Comment: There is no duplication in your code. Right now, your code is the best option. Maybe you want to edit your question to include actual duplication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Custom Approach**

You can create your own method which will log to all destinations:

```
public void Log(string message) {
    Log.Debug(message);
    Console.WriteLine(message);
}
```

From now on you simply call your newly created `Log` method:

```
Log("stating app");
```

And it will log to both destinations...

---

**Framework Approach**

There are many frameworks which tackle this problem. *e.g. log4net*
Check out [@Hany Habib's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50326107/1139105) for more detail:

Answer (score 1):

For code duplication you can create common method which is called

```
public void Log(string message,Source source) // Source is Enum to check to print on screen or file or both for example
{
     switch(source)
        {
          Case Source.Screen:
                Console.WriteLine(message);
                break;
          Case Source.Log:
               Log.Debug(message);
               break;
          default:
             break;
        }
}
```

This is for simple logging further more you can use Log4Net which gives you huge amount of logging facilities only using some configurations And guide below

https://stackify.com/log4net-guide-dotnet-logging/